# Rewrite with haccess an old url with unknown subfolders to a an url with only the first "subfolder" from old url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a weird redirect in htaccess but i don't know how to do.

I have old urls like:

```
 1. www.oldsite.com/known-old-folder/unknown-subfolder-1
 2. www.oldsite.com/known-old-folder/unknown-subfolder-2/unknown-second-subfolder-1
```

i have to redirect respectively to new urls like:

```
 1. www.newsite.com/known-new-folder/unknown-subfolder-1
 2. www.newsite.com/known-new-folder/unknown-subfolder-2
```

I don't want to consider "unknown-second-subfolder-1" if present.

How can i do in htaccess?
I don't know what to do in my **RewriteRule** to ignore the "unknown-second-subfolder-1" if present.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @anubhava change the URL in browser ;-), the new domain must be visible. Thanks!

Comment: ok thanks I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this redirect rule in `known-old-folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/known-old-folder/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/known-new-folder/%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi sir, could you please do let me know what is the significance of R=301 here? Without that also it should work right sir?

Comment: Without R=301 this rule will use default redirect default code 302

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward. You need to implement a redirection along the lines of the following rule inside your old site's configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/? https://new.example.com/new/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).